# Cleansing location data for Tableau

Tags: python, pandas, tableau-api, data-science, data-cleaning

I want to create a map view in Tableau highlighting which states in the US interact most with the New York Times online. Data was provided by Kaggle and one column shows custom location input from users. After using advanced filter in Excel, I found there are roughly 13,000 unique values.

Ex.

- "NY"
- "santa rosa, ca"
- "Brussels"
- "Nowhere Really"
- "In a pickle"
- "Milky Way"
- "Cresskill, NJ"

The format is greatly inconsistent. Are there any online guides or best practices suggesting how to clean location data? I want to preserve as much data as possible while excluding all nonsense data.

Answer (score 0):

If there's a pattern within your geo-location data, you could try REGEX functions in Tableau to extract the portion you want. Here's a quick descriptions of what REGEX functions have in Tableau and what they do : https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/functions_functions_additional.htm.
Or else I would clean the data using other programming languages before you dump into Tableau.

Comment: Thanks for your input Amy. Unfortunately, it is difficult to detect a pattern because the data is inconsistent.